# Creating a free online dungeon map maker - advice on where I can find tiles to offer the users?

Tags: map-making, dungeon, tiles

I have been looking around on various dungeon map making tools and I have not yet found one I am comfortable with. So I am thinking of creating my own online HTML5 dungeon map tool and share it with others.

My question is; where could I find tiles (and other images) I could use as assets for the online tool? Most tile-sets I have found are "for personal use", but publishing these online for "anyone" to use would probably break the license.

Where can I find tiles I could use? For free or commercial, as long as it can be part of the online tool so both myself and any visitor could use them.

**Update 11 aug 2013:**
Looking for fantasy / D&D dungeon themed assets. Both cave, dungeon and perhaps inside a house. Any common format (PNG, JPEG, GIF, PDG) as I can convert them into what I need.

The biggest challenge, I think, is finding a library of different tiles that I can use online (for others). I don't mind "buying" commercial tiles, as long as I can share them online for others to use together with the tool. So any advice would be much appreciated :-)

**Update 12 aug 2013:**
To give a move narrow description. I am looking for basic core tiles of different environments such as a cave, dungeon, inside buildings, etc. Rectangular tiles, minimum 100x100px large. Doesn't have to be 3d rendered, basic low-level works.

To give an example, tiles such as Heroic Maps would be awesome (but the license on them are "for personal use").

http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/117470/Heroic-Maps-Torchlit-Dungeon-1

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like this is a bit broad; there are hundreds of tilesets out there, each with a different theme, and each useful for different purposes. They all have different sizes, etc. I would suggest narrowing down what it is you're looking for; as-is, there are way too many possible good answers. With that said, what kinds of tile sets are you interested in?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with tilesets, but I imagine that file format, file size, file dimensions, resolution, and color profile might be significant requirements that don't even touch on whether you want fantasy, scifi, modern, urban, rural... If you can narrow down the question by elaborating on your prerequisites, we'll be able to give you an answer that's actually helpful!

Comment: Although I don't have anything concrete, I would strongly suspect that you'll find it hard to locate commercially available tiles that allow you to share them with anyone that uses your tool unless you negotiate specific licenses

Comment: Probably :-) But I don't want to overlook any options at all :-)

Comment: @corgrath I agree with the others that this is too broad. You are, inherently, looking for a _lot_ of options - but you do have criteria, I think. For instance: high quality, square grid, free to use or available for commercial usage, _preferably a large repository_, decently accessible by a webservice, etc. Find the criteria to narrow what you're after and which _do_ eliminate the sites you'd _ideally_ rather not have to deal with - forget not wanting to overlook any options, because that makes this too broad. As is, this asks for _almost_ every resource ever, and doesn't work in this format.

Comment: Since you have enough rep, you could come and work on your question with us in chat, by the way.

Answer (score 10):

We can't enumerate every possibility, but I can show you how to find such things. You want to use the search engine query [`creative commons dungeon tiles`](https://www.google.ca/search?q=creative+commons+dungeon+tiles) and variations thereon to find images you can use under a [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/), which will work for your purpose in most cases. CC licensing is the overwhelmingly most common license for art assets that can be reused in projects like yours.

For example, running that query through Google I found the site [Fantastic Maps](http://www.fantasticmaps.com/free-stuff/), which offers among other things a dungeon tileset under the Attribution Non-Commercial Share-Alike variant of the Creative Commons licenses, which would work perfectly for at least one dungeon type (underground fantasy) on a no-charge, ad-free web-based tool.

That was just the first positive hit I got though, and I mention it here only as an example for how effective search for CC-licensed works can be for you purposes. Looking through more search results and varying the search terms should find a lot of options for you to evaluate.

Comment: Can I ask how you acquired the tiles? Did you personally acquire them and then put it on the internet as CC-BY-NC-SA?

Comment: No, no, that not my site, it's someone else's. I just found it by googling. Judging by the other maps and their captions they're a member of the Cartographer's Guild site, the members of which produce a lot of maps for fun, so it's no surprise that they would give then away CC'd or for personal use. (Notice there are a few different licenses for the things on that page—not everything is CC.)

Comment: @corgath Anyway, just to clear that, you can't buy art in restrictive license, and then release then in any CC license, even if you paid for it. You still need the author permission.

Answer (score 4):

The [Liberated Pixel Cup](http://lpc.opengameart.org/) provided beautiful tilesets, that I think could help you. I think [this](http://opengameart.org/lpc-art-entries) is the correct link to them. You can also explore the [Open Game Art](http://opengameart.org/) site for open art for open games. You can filter by art type and license, which is ideal to search for art for what you specifically intend.